# contentEditable, execCommand, and forcing newly typed text to be bolded

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, execcommand

I'm fooling around with contentEditable and execCommand, and I'm trying to make it so that when a button is pressed,

- If there's text selected in the contentEditable, it becomes bolded
- If there's no text selected in the contentEditable, then any text typed in the contentEditable after pressing the button is bolded

I tried using the following Javascript command:

```
 document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
```

But unfortunately, that only causes text that's selected to become bolded; if no text is selected and you start typing after pressing the button, the text shows up unbolded.

I noticed that if I press Ctrl+B in the contentEditable, it does exactly what I'd like to accomplish, but I'd like to accomplish this using Javascript (and without simulating a Ctrl+B in Javascript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the `document.execCommand()` call does exactly what you want (you can prove this by calling it from a `keydown` event handler), and I suspect it's the effect of whatever button or whatever else you may be using to trigger the command that's the problem.

Comment: You're right. I believe the problem was focus-related (I'm embedding a browser control in my application) and after fixing that, newly typed text does become bolded after the document.execCommand() call. Thank you!

Comment: How about trying to set Underline, for example, and Italic, then type something and have the text use both formats?

Answer (score 0):

Javascripts Range can check out selected text, see [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range). You can use it to get the selected text (startnode, endnode, offset etc). If you want new text to be bold, just add it in a new created `<p>` that you give bold in css. BUT, this might not work in IE...